# Prove that $f(z) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{z^{2^k}}{2^k}$ is continuous in the closed unit disc and holomorphic inside it.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, summation, power-series

I have started off by assuming that there is a disc of radius $r$ for which $|z|<r$ for $r \in (0,1)$ and $z \in D_r$.

This implies that $|z|^{2^k} < r^{2^k}$

And after that, I don't know where to go

This problem has given me nightmares

Comment: What is your question, precisely? Are you contending the function represented by this power series is holomorphic on the *closed* unit disk?

Comment: I reckon so. Question has been edited

Comment: No, that's definitely not right. Since the radius of convergence is $1$, there must be at least one point on the boundary circle past which the function can *not* be analytically continued.

Comment: Use Morera's Theorem and interchange summation and integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is holomorphic in the open unit disc and it is continuous in the closed unit disc.

1. $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $D$. This is obtained simply by using the root test for power series. We have $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, where
   $$
   a_n=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
   2^{-k} & n=2^k, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.
   \end{array}
   \right.
   $$
   Thus
   $$
   \lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
   \lvert 2^{-k}\rvert^{1/2^k} & n=2^k, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.
   \end{array}
   \right.
   $$
   So, $\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}$ contains infinitely many terms of the sequence $n^{1/n}$ and infinitely many terms of the zero sequence, which implies that
   $$
   \limsup_{n\to\infty}\lvert a_n\rvert^{1/n}=1,
   $$
   and thus the radius of convergence of $f$ is equal to $1$, and finally, $f$ is analytic in the open unit disc, and not in any larger disc.
2. $f(z)$ is continuous in $\overline D$. It suffices to shoe that the sequence of continuous functions
   $$
   f_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^{2^k}}{2^k},
   $$
   converges uniformly in $\overline D$. But 
   $$
   \lvert f_m(z)-f_n(z)\rvert =\Big\lvert\sum_{n<k\le m}\frac{z^{2^k}}{2^k}\Big\rvert
   \le \sum_{n<k\le m} 2^{-k} <2^{-n},
   $$
   which implies that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly Cauchy in $\overline D$, and hence uniformly convergent.

Answer (score 0):

First check that the given function is convergent in closed unit disc, that is 
it converges for the points $|z|=1$. So this defines a holomorphic function in 
open unit disc and also has a finite value at the boundary points ($|z|=1$). So it is continuous by power series representation (continuous from the left hand side as this is 
domain of definition.)

Comment: Still not sure I quite get it, sorry :(

Comment: There is sloppiness in this answer. Divergence of the series at a boundary point has little to do with continuity/analyticity of the function represented by the series. Consider the geometric series $\sum z^n$.

Comment: So just treat the problem as a regular Taylor series?